# Meaning of ^\n\n\n

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am trying to load an external markdown file in reveal.js which has been written to adhere to data separator syntax:

> You can write your content as a separate file and have reveal.js load it at runtime. Note the separator arguments which determine how slides are delimited in the external file. The data-charset attribute is optional and specifies which charset to use when loading the external file.

```
<section data-markdown="example.md"  
     data-separator="^\n\n\n"  
     data-vertical="^\n\n"  
     data-notes="^Note:"  
     data-charset="iso-8859-15">
</section>
```

I thought this should mean that within example.md that three new lines should mean a new section, and that two new lines should mean an new vertical section. However, this does not occur. I feel like I have missed something obvious like the mean of the ^ character.

Here is the reference: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/README.md

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

`"^\n\n\n"` is a regular expression meaning "3 empty lines".
`"^"` means an line start.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the "line feed", use to create a new line.

`\r` is the "carriage return"

Some systems or text editor can use both to create a new line.

Maybe you can try with this:

```
<section data-markdown="example.md"  
     data-separator="^\n\r\n\r\n\r"  
     data-vertical="^\n\r\n\r"  
     data-notes="^Note:"  
     data-charset="iso-8859-15">
</section>
```

But i'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for that, though it did not work. I'm using notepad and have tried saving as ansi, unicode and utf-8, all with the same result. In the end I switched \n for \$ etc which seemed to fix it.